# Remove padding around lightningChart

Tags: lightningchart

I want to remove all the unnecessary space around chart even if it very small , So I tried this code

```
chart[0].setPadding({ bottom: 0,left:-5 ,right:-5,top:0});
chart[1].setPadding({ bottom: -5,left:-5 ,right:-5,top:0});
```

Still I get some space in top and bottom , please see the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the screenshot is of a single dashboard. Then that line would be a dashboard splitter. You can remove it by setting the splitter style of dashboard to [`emptyFill`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/globals.html#emptyfill) with [`dashboard.setSplitterStyle`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/dashboard.html#setsplitterstyle)

```js
dashboard.setSplitterStyle(emptyFill)
```

That will remove the splitter line and let the charts to use the space it was using.

To get a chart with absolutely no unnecessary space around the chart, you will need to set:

- chart title fill style to `emptyFill`
- chart padding to 0
- all axis tick styles to `emptyTick`
- all axis stroke styles to `emptyLine`
- all axis nib styles to `emptyLine`
- dashboard splitter style to `emptyLine`
- dashboard background stroke style to `emptyLine`

See the example below for how that would look like.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    emptyLine,
    emptyTick,
    emptyFill
} = lcjs

const db = lightningChart().Dashboard({
    numberOfColumns: 1,
    numberOfRows: 2
})

const c1 = db.createChartXY({
    columnIndex: 0,
    columnSpan: 1,
    rowIndex: 0,
    rowSpan: 1
})
const c2 = db.createChartXY({
    columnIndex: 0,
    columnSpan: 1,
    rowIndex: 1,
    rowSpan: 1
})


const data = Array.from(Array(10)).map((_, i) => ({ x: i, y: Math.random() }))

const ser1 = c1.addLineSeries()
    .add(data)

const ser2 = c2.addLineSeries()
    .add(data.map((p) => ({ x: p.x, y: -p.y })))

// Hide titles and remove padding from chart
c1
    .setTitleFillStyle(emptyFill)
    .setPadding(0)
c2
    .setTitleFillStyle(emptyFill)
    .setPadding(0)

// Hide axis ticks, line and nibs
c1.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTickStyle(emptyTick)
    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
c1.getDefaultAxisY()
    .setTickStyle(emptyTick)
    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
c2.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTickStyle(emptyTick)
    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    .setNibStyle(emptyLine)
c2.getDefaultAxisY()
    .setTickStyle(emptyTick)
    .setStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
    .setNibStyle(emptyLine)

// Hide dashboard splitter and remove background stroke style.
db
    .setSplitterStyle(emptyLine)
    .setBackgroundStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey @Snekw please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035619/add-timestamp-to-image-generated-by-savetofile