# Add timestamp to image generated by SavetoFile

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Hi I was checking out the docs of chartXY of LightningChartJs and couldn't seem to find a way to add a timestamp to the image saved by saveToFile.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LightningChart JS [`saveToFile`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/chartxy.html#savetofile) doesn't support adding a timestamp.

You can achieve this by implementing your own saving.

The steps to do this is:

1. Get reference to the canvas LightningChart JS is running in.

```js
const chartCanvas = chart.engine.container.querySelector('canvas')
```

2. Convert the canvas content to a data url with [`HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

```js
const sc = chartCanvas.toDataURL('image/png')
```

3. Load that screenshot to another canvas

```js
const secondaryCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const ctx = secondaryCanvas.getContext('2d')
const img = new Image()
img.src = sc
img.onload = () => {
    // load the screenshot to another canvas
    ctx.canvas.width = width
    ctx.canvas.height = height
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
}
```

4. Add the timestamp

```js
const timeNow = new Date().toISOString()
ctx.fillStyle = '#fff'
ctx.fillText(timeNow, 0, height)
```

5. Save the canvas context to file

```js
const timestamped = ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
const fileName = 'chart.png'
const a = window.document.createElement('a')
window.document.body.appendChild(a)
const url = timestamped
a.href = url
a.download = fileName
a.click()
```

---

See a working example below, where a screenshot is stored when the button at the center of chart is clicked.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    UIElementBuilders
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const secondaryCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const ctx = secondaryCanvas.getContext('2d')

const chartCanvas = chart.engine.container.querySelector('canvas')
document.body.appendChild(secondaryCanvas)

const scButton = chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.ButtonBox)
scButton.setText('Take Screenshot with timestamp')
scButton.setPosition({ x: 50, y: 50 })
scButton.onMouseClick(() => {
    const width = chartCanvas.clientWidth
    const height = chartCanvas.clientHeight
    // screenshot the canvas
    const sc = chartCanvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    const img = new Image()
    img.src = sc
    img.onload = () => {
        // load the screenshot to another canvas
        ctx.canvas.width = width
        ctx.canvas.height = height
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
        // add time stamp
        const timeNow = new Date().toISOString()
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff'
        ctx.fillText(timeNow, 0, height)

        // save to file
        const timestamped = ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        const fileName = 'chart.png'
        const a = window.document.createElement('a')
        window.document.body.appendChild(a)
        const url = timestamped
        a.href = url
        a.download = fileName
        a.click()
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't get the chart I just see the time stamp also the above example makes a copy just below it I just want to download it.